# Unable to fetch the Ids of the child control from the parent in windows form in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have one Windows form which have groupbox and in that groupbox there is a tabcontrol and that tab control has multiple text boxes. I am not able to fetch the id's of the text boxes that are inside the tabcontrol and I have to  pass this of Windows form.

Please reply if anyone know the solution or come across this scenario

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any code that you tried for this ??

Comment: Yes, I tried to use window this but in that case I am only able to get the id's of those child control which are at one level below not beyond that ,as the code is in client machine so I cannot paste it here. I have searched for the help in Google but I did not got any help that will relate to my problem